# Eccodes generates different results when using different tools

Tags: c++, grib, eccodes

I'm using the [Eccodes API](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/ecCodes+Home) to convert GRIB2 files. When I use the C++ API to extract all `paramId` and `shortName`, V component of wind (paramId is 132 and shortName is v) is not present in the query results, as follows:

`ids=73
0 31 43 54 59 130 131 133 134 135 156 157 165 167 168 172 173 3020 3024 3041 3045 3046 3054 3063 3066 3086 228001 228002 228139 228164 228228 260002 260003 260029 260030 260031 260032 260038 260056 260065 260072 260073 260074 260083 260087 260088 260097 260098 260125 260127 260128 260155 260180 260185 260187 260189 260190 260205 260206 260207 260208 260209 260238 260242 260256 260317 260389 260390 260391
260439 260442 260509 7001353
names=73
10u 2d 2r 2t 4lftx VRATE absv acpcp al bmixl cape cd cfrzr ci cicep cin cnwat crain csnow dlwrf dswrf fricv gh gust hindex hlcy hpbl lftx lhtfl lsm ltng mslet mstav orog pli poros pres prmsl pwat q r refc refd rlyrs sde sdwe shtfl slt smdry smref snowc soill soilw sp sr ssw st t tcc tke tp u ulwrf unknown uswrf veg vgtyp vis vucsh vvcsh w wilt wz`

The program code is as follows:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2005-2017 ECMWF.
 *
 * This software is licensed under the terms of the Apache Licence Version 2.0
 * which can be obtained at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 *
 * In applying this licence, ECMWF does not waive the privileges and immunities granted to it by
 * virtue of its status as an intergovernmental organisation nor does it submit to any jurisdiction.
 */

/*
 * C Implementation: grib_index
 *
 * Description: How to create and use an index to access GRIB messages from a file
 *
 */

#include "eccodes.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    codes_index* index = NULL;
    codes_handle* h = NULL;
    int ret;
    size_t size, i;
    char** names;
    long* ids;

    index = codes_index_new_from_file(0, argv[argc - 1], "paramId,shortName", &ret);
    CODES_CHECK(ret, 0);

    CODES_CHECK(codes_index_get_size(index, "shortName", &size),0);
    ids=(long*)malloc(sizeof(long)*size);
    CODES_CHECK(codes_index_get_long(index,"paramId",ids,&size),0);
    printf("ids=%ld\n",(long)size);
    for (i=0;i<size;i++) printf("%ld ",ids[i]);
    printf("\n");

    CODES_CHECK(codes_index_get_size(index, "shortName", &size),0);
    names=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*size);
    CODES_CHECK(codes_index_get_string(index,"shortName",names,&size),0);
    printf("names=%ld\n",(long)size);
    for (i=0;i<size;i++) printf("%s ",names[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I query the parameter using `grib_ls`, it shows up:

`wuh20@sapphire:~/github/test$ grib_ls -w paramId=132 -p paramId,level,shortName,name ~/Desktop/test/nam_218_20180701_0000_000.grb2
/home/graduate/wuh20/Desktop/test/nam_218_20180701_0000_000.grb2
paramId     level       shortName   name
132         0           v           V component of wind
132         50          v           V component of wind
132         75          v           V component of wind
132         100         v           V component of wind
132         125         v           V component of wind
132         150         v           V component of wind
132         175         v           V component of wind
132         200         v           V component of wind
132         225         v           V component of wind
132         250         v           V component of wind
132         275         v           V component of wind
132         300         v           V component of wind
132         325         v           V component of wind
132         350         v           V component of wind
132         375         v           V component of wind
132         400         v           V component of wind
132         425         v           V component of wind
132         450         v           V component of wind
132         475         v           V component of wind
132         500         v           V component of wind
132         525         v           V component of wind
132         550         v           V component of wind
132         575         v           V component of wind
132         600         v           V component of wind
132         625         v           V component of wind
132         650         v           V component of wind
132         675         v           V component of wind
132         700         v           V component of wind
132         725         v           V component of wind
132         750         v           V component of wind
132         775         v           V component of wind
132         800         v           V component of wind
132         825         v           V component of wind
132         850         v           V component of wind
132         875         v           V component of wind
132         900         v           V component of wind
132         925         v           V component of wind
132         950         v           V component of wind
132         975         v           V component of wind
132         1000        v           V component of wind
132         0           v           V component of wind
132         0           v           V component of wind
132         80          v           V component of wind
132         3000        v           V component of wind
132         6000        v           V component of wind
132         9000        v           V component of wind
132         12000       v           V component of wind
132         15000       v           V component of wind
132         18000       v           V component of wind
49 of 446 messages in /home/graduate/wuh20/Desktop/test/nam_218_20180701_0000_000.grb2`

Could somebody help me figure this out?

I can provide my data if it is needed or helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a hidden but easy one. I have to turn on multi support which is ON by default in all tools.

> For all the tools default is multi support ON.

[reference](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/grib_multi)